# React Native release build error code 65 Appcenter

Tags: ios, react-native, build, code-signing, appcenter

Building a beta version of a react native mobile app for store apple store release.

Appcenter build fails with exit code 65

If it is not related to the provisioning profile / certificates, it seems related to my constant CompileC / DerivedData issue that I've been getting since I moved the project to build on a m1 in xcode 13, we used to be on xcode 12.

I've built a number of times with no luck. This is not the first beta release.

I have since changed the Pods that are providing warnings with the packages and I still see the pod target warnings? reinstalled pods, but I still see that the deployment target warnings.

```
info: -> RNFB build script started
info: 1) Locating firebase.json file:
info:      (1 of 2) Searching in '/Users/runner/work/1/s' for a firebase.json file.
info:      (2 of 2) Searching in '/Users/runner/work/1' for a firebase.json file.
warning:   A firebase.json file was not found, whilst this file is optional it is recommended to include it to configure firebase services in React Native Firebase.
info: 2) Injecting Info.plist entries: 
    ->  0) firebase_json_raw string e30=
info:      setting plist entry 'firebase_json_raw' of type 'string' in file '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dvxnpszzuvotxigpxdfrhjzaxorw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Info.plist'
warning:   A Info.plist build output file was not found (/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dvxnpszzuvotxigpxdfrhjzaxorw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist)
info: <- RNFB build script finished

CopySwiftLibs /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dvxnpszzuvotxigpxdfrhjzaxorw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
    cd /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign C4F757742A9695D4006EE7922E6204EB117E7DD3 --scan-executable /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dvxnpszzuvotxigpxdfrhjzaxorw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp --scan-folder /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dvxnpszzuvotxigpxdfrhjzaxorw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dvxnpszzuvotxigpxdfrhjzaxorw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/PlugIns --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dvxnpszzuvotxigpxdfrhjzaxorw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Ar...
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dvxnpszzuvotxigpxdfrhjzaxorw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp' (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')

/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'react-native-maps' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'react-native-blob-util' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'BVLinearGradient' from project 'Pods')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed)
##[section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)
==============================================================================
Task         : Xcode
Description  : Build, test, or archive an Xcode workspace on macOS. Optionally package an app.
Version      : 4.130.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613730)
==============================================================================
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11227) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed)
##[section]Starting: Install Apple provisioning profile
==============================================================================
Task         : Install Apple Provisioning Profile
Description  : Install an Apple provisioning profile required to build on a macOS agent
Version      : 0.124.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : 
==============================================================================
##[warning]Deleting provisioning profile: /Users/runner/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/05f8c808-76d9-40bd-956a-2cd148102ad2.mobileprovision
[command]/bin/rm -f /Users/runner/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/05f8c808-76d9-40bd-956a-2cd148102ad2.mobileprovision
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:11228) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
##[section]Finishing: Install Apple provisioning profile
##[section]Starting: Install Apple certificate
==============================================================================
Task         : Install Apple certificate
Description  : Install an Apple certificate required to build on a macOS agent machine
Version      : 2.200.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-certificate
==============================================================================
[command]/usr/bin/security delete-keychain /Users/runner/work/_temp/ios_signing_temp.keychain
##[section]Finishing: Install Apple certificate
##[section]Starting: Checkout git-4bb2ed81-eb08-455f-9655-7a9e4e196ada@dk_beta_3.9_test2 to s
==============================================================================
Task         : Get sources
Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
Version      : 1.0.0
Author       : Microsoft
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
==============================================================================
Cleaning any cached credential from repository: git-4bb2ed81-eb08-455f-9655-7a9e4e196ada (ExternalGit)
##[section]Finishing: Checkout git-4bb2ed81-eb08-455f-9655-7a9e4e196ada@dk_beta_3.9_test2 to s
##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
Cleaning up task key
Start cleaning up orphan processes.
##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
##[section]Finishing: Build
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed the arm64 from 'Excluded Architectures' for the Release build in xcode. This solved the issue.